# Crystal Reports: Setting subreport parameters with one main report parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have been unable to find an answer to my question via searching, however do not entirely understand Crystal so might be glossing over the information I need. Apologies if this is the case!

I have 'inherited' a reporting role from somebody who has left my organisation, and am frankensteining some of his old reports to get the data requested of me.

The main report I use (reports on service request statistics for an IT Support Service) consists of (usually) between 10-15 sub-reports. I alter the select expert parameters on each of these sub-reports depending on what I need.

I would very much like to alter a given parameter on the main report (namely my `insert_date` field and have this parameter updated on every one of the sub-reports. As it stands, I am editing the date parameter on each sub-report individually, which is obviously very time consuming.

I am pretty much an absolute Crystal beginner and have very little training - I was given these inherited reports and shown how to refresh & export. Now that reporting requirements are changing I'm left to fiddle and try to work things out for myself, so really really appreciate any guiding words anybody can offer!

Comment: are you adding a new parameter in main report? and want to reflect the same in all your sub reports?

Comment: Hi Siva, that is exactly what I'd like to do!

Comment: When you are creating sub report links, Try to select the date parameter from main report and link the date filed of the sub report and check whether it reflects in sub report select expert, And run the report. check the data. Currently I don't have the CR tool with me, Can you check this

Comment: Reason I am advicing is anyway you are linking your sub report parameter in select expert.. so do this instead of creating the parameter again in sub report as main report and sub report parameter will be linked anyway